# Issue with jqplot legend and CSS float

Tags: css, css-float, jqplot

I have a problem using the jqplot chart legend.
I have a chart and a legend at the top of it. 
The legend is a `table`, every color and text field together are `tr`.
I set `float: left;` CSS property to `tr` elements and `max-width` CSS property to the `table` element because I want legend and chart with the same width. The position of legend is set automatically from the jqplot options.
In **IE9** it works perfectly as you can see from this image:

http://s13.postimage.org/61f0ks5uf/image.png

But the problem comes from **Chrome**:

http://s13.postimage.org/4jtk9813r/chrome.png

As you can see the legend is over the container but i want legend dimension like IE.
How can I do?
Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Could you post an example with JSFiddle.net so we can see all the relevant CSS?

Comment: Fortunately, while I was writing the code, I solved the problem. This lesson taught me that JSFiddler is a great tool and I must use it before post new questions. Anyway, the problem was that I had a div container with `white-space: nowrap;` CSS property. This is the code: [http://jsfiddle.net/FjGyC/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/FjGyC/11/) if you want to take a look. Thank you Anson.

Comment: Glad that helped! If this answer would help other people, then it is good practice to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Test with a legend in two lines.

Something like that:

```
 legend: {
           show: true,
           location: 'n',
           placement: 'outside',
           rendererOptions: {
                  numberRows: 2                           
           }
         }
```